# Download file after fill in email address

Tags: 7

When anonymous users wants to download e.g a PDF file, they must first fill in their email address. What is best way to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way without resorting to coding would be setting up a [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) that the user is required to fill out, containing only one email field, and putting the link to the PDF in the completion message.

If you need strict access control on the PDF, you can setup your site with [Email Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration) and [Generate Password](https://www.drupal.org/project/genpass), and redirect the user after registration to a node that is visible only to authenticated users. Add a file field using the private file system to the content type and attach the PDF to the node.

Comment: but is it then also (basically) possible, users be able to reach the PDF file without the completion message? In other worths, it should be something quit secure and users are not be able to see the PDF on the server. Only after fill in their email address.